# Ansible hide ok: [web] output but display msg

Tags: ansible

how can I hide the **ok: [web]** output on terminal but display the msg on the terminal.

[image]

This is what I have in the ansible.cfg file. If I set display_ok_hosts=**false**, nothing will display on the terminal.
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback *community.general.selective*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t callback selective
```

Quoting:

> This callback only prints tasks that have been tagged with `print_action` or that have failed.

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: web
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd
        
    - assert:
        that:
          - getent_passwd._apt.5 == '/usr/sbin/nologin'
          - getent_passwd._rpc.5 == '/usr/sbin/nologin'
          - getent_passwd._chrony.5 == '/usr/sbin/nologin'
        success_msg: "[PASSED] - Ensure system accounts are non-login"
      tags: [print_action]
```

shows the output of all tasks when *default* callback is used

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [web] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [getent] ********************************************************************************
ok: [web]

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [web] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "[PASSED] - Ensure system accounts are non-login"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
web: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The output is limited to the enabled task when the *selective* callback is used

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=selective ansible-playbook pb.yml
.
# assert ******************************************************************************************************************
  * web                        - changed=False --------------------------------------------------
    [PASSED] - Ensure system accounts are non-login

# STATS *******************************************************************************************************************
web: ok=2   changed=0   failed=0    unreachable=0   rescued=0   ignored=0
```

Comment: Is there another way of doing this? I want to run the playbook with no additional text.

Comment: Then use [*ansible-runner*](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and display what you want. As a hint see my [wrapper](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html#wrapper-ansible-runner).